# Check file content type

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, file-handling, android-file

Need to check the type of file being picked from intent.

**Scenario**: if 'example.exe' is renamed to 'example.doc' than while picking the 
file from explorer in the application than file type should be detected as **exe** not **doc**.

**Expected:** If some file is picked from file-explorer than it's need to check the file type by using the orignal content of the file.

Used getMimeType method for file but no luck

Comment: First four bytes contains information about the file type. Check [this](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic) project and also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)